# Spring Roo + GWT - Persistence problem with HSQLDB Database

Tags: gwt, jpa, hsqldb, spring-roo

I am using Spring Roo to develop a project in GWT. After trying a few samples can not still persist objects in the database. Each time I restart or reload data from the tables, values disappear.
This is my log.roo file

```
// Spring Roo 1.1.2.RELEASE [rev fbc33bb] log opened at 2011-04-12 14:38:57
project --topLevelPackage com.despesas
persistence setup --provider HIBERNATE --database HYPERSONIC_PERSISTENT
enum type --class ~.shared.domain.Genero
enum constant --name HOMEM
enum constant --name MULHER
entity --class ~.server.domain.Funcionario --testAutomatically
field string --fieldName Nome --notNull
field string --fieldName userName --sizeMin 3 --sizeMax 30 --notNull
field string --fieldName departmento
field reference --type Funcionario supervisor
field enum --fieldName sexo --type ~.shared.domain.Genero
field boolean --fieldName admin --notNull
entity --class ~.server.domain.Report --testAutomatically
field string --fieldName proposta
field string --fieldName notas
field date --fieldName criado --type java.util.Date
field string --fieldName departamento
field reference --type Funcionario reporter
field reference --type Funcionario AprovacaoSupervisor
entity --class ~.server.domain.Despesa --testAutomatically
field number --type java.lang.Double montante
field string --fieldName descricao
field reference --type Report report
field string --fieldName aprovacao
field string --fieldName categoria
field date --fieldName criado --type java.util.Date
field string --fieldName motivoRecusa
gwt setup
logging setup --level INFO
quit
dependency add --groupId com.google.appengine --artifactId appengine-api-1.0-sdk --version 1.4.0
quit
perform eclipse
quit
```

Would I be making a wrong configuration in persistence.xml file or HSQLDB Database is not recommended to deposit and maintain persistence.

This is my persistence.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
            <!-- value="create" to build a new database on each run; value="update" to modify an existing database; value="create-drop" means the same as "create" but also drops tables when Hibernate closes; value="validate" makes no changes to the database -->
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>
            <!-- Uncomment the following two properties for JBoss only -->
            <!-- property name="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl" value="false" /-->
            <!-- property name="hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners" value="false" /-->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I´ve changed `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>` to `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>` after creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I would use a different database. HSQLDB does not keep data on disk, only in memory. I'm using MYSQL and I'm happy. I'll attach an example for you to see how I set the log file.

```
project --topLevelPackage com.something
persistence setup --provider HIBERNATE --database MYSQL --databaseName myDb --userName root --password admin
```

and so on..
Then import to eclipse in the roo shell with `perform eclipse` and edit the parameters in **src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/database.properties** and **src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml**.
Hope it helps..

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped me a lot. Didn´t understood very well HSQLDB and saw a lot of examples that i was thinking another thing.

Answer (score 3):

Persistent HSQLDB is supported. If you look at this page:

http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/base-persistence.html

This example is given for a memory database:

```
A database properties file (src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/database.properties) which contains user name, password, JDBC driver name and connection URL details:

database.url=jdbc\:hsqldb\:mem\:foo
database.username=sa
database.password=
database.driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
```

You should change it to:

`database.url=jdbc\:hsqldb\:file\:foo`

The database is now a file database, with a set of files: foo.properties, foo.log etc.

You can add properties to the URL, as described in the HSQLDB Guide, in order to control various persistence options.

Alternatively, start an HSQLDB Server, and use `\:hsql` instead of `\:file`